# DynamicData - How to bind to grouped data

Tags: c#, system.reactive, observablecollection, dynamic-data

I'm using DynamicData from Roland Pheasant.

[DynamicData](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData/wiki/Introduction-for-ReactiveUI-users)

I would like to convert my normal C# collections to Rx.

From 
`ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, DisplayItem>>`

to DynamicData format

`ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IGroup<DisplayItem, string>>` or
`ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IGroup<DisplayItem, string, string>>`

for cached source.

Currently my xaml will look as follows to bind on normal `ObservableCollection<Grouping<string, DisplayItem>>`

`<CollectionViewSource
                    x:Name="GroupedDataCollection"
                    Source="{x:Bind ViewModel.bindingData_grouped, Mode=OneWay}"
                    IsSourceGrouped="True" />`

```
        <ListView 
                      Margin="16,0"
                      ItemsSource="{x:Bind GroupedDataCollection.View , Mode=OneWay}"
                      SelectionMode="None">

            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="False">
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="14"
                                           FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                           Text="{Binding  Key }" />

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:DisplayItem">
                    <StackPanel>

                        <TextBlock FontSize="14"
                                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                       Text="{x:Bind Description  }" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Model :

```
    public class DisplayItem {
    public string ID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public string Type { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public double? Price { get; set; } = 0; }
```

Existing c# Observable Collection Results:
[image: Existing results]

Dynamic Data Code :

`public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IGroup<DisplayItem, string>>        bindingData_grouped;`

`var myBindingOperation_grouped = Data.ToObservableChangeSet()
                   .GroupOn(x => x.Type)
                   .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                   .Bind(out bindingData_grouped)
                   .Subscribe();`

Using above code if I bind to `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IGroup<DisplayItem, string>>` or `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IGroup<DisplayItem, string, string>>` my listview displays nothing.

How do I bind from xaml listview using "CollectionViewSource" to a 
`ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IGroup<DisplayItem, string>>`  or
`ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IGroup<DisplayItem, string, string>>`

thks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am new to DynamicData so I might be re-implementing something that already exists in the lib, but this is what I came up with:

```
// custom IGrouping implementation which is required by ListView
public class Grouping<TKey, TElement> : ObservableCollectionExtended<TElement>, IGrouping<TKey, TElement>
{
    public Grouping(IGroup<TElement, TKey> group) 
    {
        if (group == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(group));
        }

        Key = group.GroupKey;
        group.List.Connect().Bind(this).Subscribe();
    }

    public TKey Key { get; private set; }
}

// this.Ints is an ObservableCollection<int> which I manipulate thru UI
this.Ints
    .ToObservableChangeSet()
    .GroupOn(i => (int)(i / 10)) // group by 10s
    .Transform(group => new Grouping<int, int>(group)) // transform DynamicData IGroup into our IGrouping implementation
    .Sort(SortExpressionComparer<Grouping<int, int>>.Ascending(t => t.Key)) // sort by keys
    .ObserveOnDispatcher()
    .Bind(this.GroupedInts) // this.GroupedInts is used as binding source for CollectionViewSource in UI
    .Subscribe();

private ObservableCollectionExtended<Grouping<int, int>> GroupedInts { get; } = new ObservableCollectionExtended<Grouping<int, int>>();
```

Basically you need a custom implementation of IGrouping interface required by ListView's (CollectionViewSource's) grouping mechanism. You pass it an instance of IGroup (which comes from DynamicData's `GroupOn` method). In the constructor you Connect() to the group's ReactiveList and bind it to the `Grouping` itself.

Comment: For your reassurance, you've implemented it how it's recommended in the [Xamarin.Forms example](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData.Snippets/blob/master/DynamicData.Snippets/Group/XamarinFormsGrouping.cs). You may just want Grouping to implement `IDisposable` and call `DisposeMany`.