# Display preprocessed dynamic data with out-of-the-box WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, system.reactive, dynamic-data

EDIT 2; That accepted answer on the linked StackOverflow question doesn't actually work for me. It compiles and looks fine, but it doesn't visualize the data like the picture in the question (again, for me). I see a flat list of rows containing a grouping object, not rows of the actual item source grouped together.
The answer doesn't explicitly mention a DataGrid, but a ListView. Both controls use the same CollectionView object per collection, so what should work for ListView will also work for DataGrid.
It also doesn't show how the binding is done with a WPF control. Either this approach worked at one point and isn't working anymore, or it hasn't worked ever.
Both my question and the linked one are about using DynamicData to do the filtering that one normally uses ListCollectionView for in out-of-the-box WPF. Flattening the items and doing grouping, sorting, and filtering with the default ListCollectionView would defeat the purpose, be it for performance or usability reasons.
This question might have become an XY problem because of my reasoning that WPF controls only understand ICollectionView, me having DynamicData data, and an adapter bridging both sounds logical.

EDIT 1; To be clear; I'm talking about a situation where I end up with a changeset of grouped objects eg `IObservable<IChangeSet<T>>` where T is `ItemGroup: System.Linq.IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`.
The issue lies with properly communicating to the data grid control that the source of items is already pre-grouped (aka hierarchical).
I became aware that mentioning pre-sorted and pre-filtered possibly created confusion by not being to the point.

I'm looking for a demonstration on how to visualize pre-sorted, -filtered, and -grouped data coming from DynamicData through a WPF Datagrid control.
My intention is to create XAML code as if the ItemsSource was a ListCollectionView. The data would be produced by Dynamic Data changeset operators bound into an observable collection.

There are two snippets, that I could find, which hint at a possibility to combine "out of the box" WPF data grid with DynamicData;

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52928955
- https://github.com/RolandPheasant/DynamicData.Snippets/blob/master/DynamicData.Snippets/Group/XamarinFormsGrouping.cs

Both have to do with implementing the correct interfaces so glue code within WPF can handle the rest. I tested the suggestions but couldn't get it to work; The grid simply shows my outermost object properties eg ItemGroup.Key and ItemGroup.Count. My expectation being the grid displays records of the grouped objects where the group container is defined by my group style template. The grid simply acts as if the item source is a flat list of items (in reality pre-grouped).
In so far I understood the reference source this is not actually supported.

A second attempt was made by implementing a custom CollectionView that should proxy between the DynamicData result and the data grid control. At best I could produce some visual glitches; it didn't work either.

I'm either not clever enough to see the obvious issue or integrating with WPF controls is just hard.
Please direct me on how to solve this issue, or point me to code that behaves as desired.

I'm not afraid to create my own glue code or extensions if necessary. Maybe WPF isn't suited for this type of request in which case alternative suggestions are welcomed.
Up until this topic I considered myself a decently skilled programmer but this roadblock hits me hard mentally.

Comment: DynamicData supports binding from the `SourceList<T>` or `SourceCache<T>` directly to a normal collection for display purposes. You can just call `mySourceList.Connect().Bind(myObservableCollection).Subscribe();` to have the changes in the `SourceList<T>` object be automatically mapped to the `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: @BrandonKramer Your comment made me aware that I didn't get to the point. I have added some clarification.

Comment: I see what you are struggling with now.  The problem is that you are essentially trying to bind a single grid to changeset from a list of lists.  The solution in this case is to flatten the groups into a single list, and then perform any visual grouping on the grid itself.  Either that, or you could try using nested grids (Eg a grid where each row is another grid) although that could be quite a pain to create, and may not look very nice without a lot of work.

Comment: WPF has ICollectionView and ICollectionViewLiveShaping which already present a (multi)grouped, filtered, and sorted view into the ItemsSource object. I'm hoping someone can tell me if and how an adapter between ICollectionView and DynamicData would work.. or maybe another way to achieve the desired goal.

Comment: CollectionViews are implicitly used every time you bind to a collection.  Its not something that you generally need to create or work with yourself.  What you need to do is convert your IEnumerable<IChangeSet<ItemGroup>> into a form that WPF knows how to bind to.  The easiest way to do that would just be to flatten the collection via Select().Merge(). If you don't want to convert the data in your viewmodel just use WPF data templates in your view as previously mentioned to make each row its own grid or listview or other collection display object.

Comment: Alternatively, the linked question found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094572/dynamicdata-how-to-bind-to-grouped-data?noredirect=1&lq=1 shows a means of using DynamicData to bind to grouped data.

Comment: Yes, it would be great to not require implementing a custom ICollectionView, but the default one doesn't seem to support a pre-grouped item source; I cannot make the code of the answer work with the System.Linq.IGrouping interface, nor do i find code actually handling objects of that type in the WPF referencesource.
I updated the question with another edit to clarify further.

Comment: The core issue with what you are doing is that most of these controls (Such as DataGrid) are designed to display a single collection, whereas what you wish to display is a collection of collections.  Messing with the collectionview is not really the solution here because a DataGrid simply isn't designed to be bound to multiple collections at the same time.

Comment: Any solution for this problem will require either flattening the list before binding it, or writing the xaml structure for the DataGrid in such a way as to display nested collections.  If you are unwilling to change the format of the collection, WPF does provide the tools to define nested elements via DataTemplate for the DataGrid's rows.  You will just need to decide which solution you prefer, and solutions for either can be readily found on the internet.  If you want, let me know which you prefer and I can even try to help you find a solution.

Comment: Also, in regards to your edit, you are conflating visual grouping with collection grouping.  The DataGrid will display groups based on what grouping settings you define in its xaml.  It isn't going to know anything about underlying groups or how to display them if you don't define them in xaml.  The CollectionView is not a means to make the DataGrid show groups, it is a means to enable grouping/filter/sorting of the source data without actually modifying that source.

Comment: And finally, remember that IObservable<T> is not something that you can simply bind to in WPF or any other UI architecture that I am aware of, since an IObservable is a push based event analog, not really a collection in the sense that a DataGrid is meant to display.  Regardless of other means, you will need to bind the output from the SourceList or SourceCache to some kind of collection object, such as the ObservableCollection or ObservableCollectionExtended that is provided by DynamicData.

Comment: I agree with the statement that the controls are designed for a single collection. I also agree that the CollectionView is designed to provide grouping information from a flat list. I understand the view part in CollectionView and didn't intend to create confusion around both words. It should be possible to do the reverse; create a (generic) view that can allows DataGrid to display DynamicData's grouping construct.

Comment: @BrandonKramer I dove into the CollectionView code today and found out that CollectionViewGroupRoot, used as group generator, actually creates CollectionViewGroup classes for each unique value from applying available GroupDescriptor-s. Since I already have group objects available i suspect the question to be answered by implementing a visitor pattern to enumerate all leaf objects and wrapping/transforming the group objects into CollectionViewGroup objects. This code is hardcoded against (internal) types instead of interfaces which caused my confusion between behaviour and properties.

Comment: Not only are the group objects created hierarchically, the object also contains a leaf enumerator class to flatten the group objects again through the Enumerable interface. It has certainly been made complex imo.

Comment: To clarify; CollectionViewGroupRoot creates CollectionViewInternal objects, which inherit from CollectionViewGroup. All the code in CollectionView and dependencies is hardcoded to types, so it's confusing which type contains behaviour and which type holds important properties to bind to through XAML.
CollectionViewGroupRoot has a leaf enumerator to present a flat collection from the generated groups instead of the original source collection. I suspect i have to to the same high level tasks in my DynamicData adapter.

Comment: Added an answer to hopefully illustrate what I was trying to explain in a better fashion.  Also, sorry for the delay in getting back to you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to display pre-grouped data (ex: `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`) in a WPF DataGrid is simply to use data templates to display the group contents in a nested DataGrid.

Example:

```
<Window x:Class="GroupingDisplay.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GroupingDisplay"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GroupingData}" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Data, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace GroupingDisplay
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public List<IGrouping<int, TestClass>> GroupingData { get; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var testData = new TestClass[]
            {
                new TestClass(1, "Horse"),
                new TestClass(1, "Cow"),
                new TestClass(2, "Bike"),
                new TestClass(2, "Car"),
                new TestClass(3, "House"),
                new TestClass(3, "Hotel")
            };

            GroupingData = testData
                .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
                .ToList();

            DataContext = this;
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public int Key { get; }
        public string Data { get; }

        public TestClass(int key, string data)
        {
            Key = key;
            Data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

The above simple class will display 3 rows, one for each group (1, 2, and 3).
Then when you click on a row, it will expand and show the contents of that group.

[image: The Grid - No Selected Row]

[image: The Grid - First Row Selected]

If you want to show all group contents automatically, you can set the Parent DataGrid's `RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible"`.

[image: The Grid - All Groups Visible]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write out a completed example on control nesting. In the meantime I attempted building a custom listcollectionview that wraps already grouped data, and it works. I built a PoC here: https://github.com/Bert-Proesmans/dynamic-data-collectionview. All that's left is generalizing and building an intuitive API to generate the required objects.